# CircularPercentIndicator with dynamic Value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to show CircularPercentIndicator with dynmaic value,i am getting value from api example like "12.7" i can show that into Text child of CircularPercentIndicator but i need to show the color of CircularPercentIndicator according to "12.7" i can only pass double value.
i am using [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator)

```
           Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                        radius: 55.0,
                        lineWidth: 8.0,
                        animation: true,
                        percent: 0.7,
                        center: new Text(
                           data.percentage + "%",,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 11.0),
                        ),
                        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                        progressColor: Colors.green[700],
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, then, the problem is

> You are not able to show the correct percentage on the `CircularPercentIndicator`, but you are able to show the text for that Widget

If that is the case, after reading the documentation, and looking at your code, I believe the thing which you're doing wrong is to write the percentage as exact `0.7` and pass it to `percent` which takes care of your color of the progress, and not the value coming from API.

In order to make it dynamic, use your `data.percentage` only, which is I believe shows the data in your text as well.

To pass the data into the `percent` as double, you can use the data as `double.parse(any_value)`

*I am assuming that, the `data.percentage` update is being taken care of by your method only*

**Code**

```
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                        radius: 55.0,
                        lineWidth: 8.0,
                        animation: true,
                        percent: double.parse(data.percentage) / 100, // here we're using the percentage to be in sync with the color of the text
                        center: new Text(
                           data.percentage + "%",,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 11.0),
                        ),
                        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                        progressColor: Colors.green[700],
                      )
                    )
```

To know more about type casting the string data to double, read bout [String to Double dart](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/string+to+double+dart).

Comment: I have got it,but i tried your there this problem arise `The method 'toDouble' isn't defined for the type 'String'.`.but thanks for the help, i have manged to do like this `percent: double.parse(data.percentage) / 100` @Alok

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad, `toDouble` is meant for type `int` not `String`. For `string`, it is always data_type.parse(). I am going to edit my answer, so that people won't get confused in the future. Thanks @Morbius. You helped me!

Comment: you need to divide the converted value to 100 because the `percent` only accept 0.0 to 1.0,if doesn't it will throw error like this `Exception: Percent value must be a double between 0.0 and 1.0`. @Alok

Comment: Hmm, I was not aware of the value you're getting from the API, thought, it was `12.7` only. I will rectify that. Thanks again  @Morbius :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  double value;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // you just have to divide by 100
    value = 12.7 / 100;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
      child: CircularPercentIndicator(
        radius: 55.0,
        lineWidth: 8.0,
        animation: true,
        percent: value,
        center: new Text(
          '12.7',
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 11.0),
        ),
        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
        progressColor: Colors.green[700],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the logic, i have manged to do this in 1 line  `percent: double.parse(data.percentage) / 100` ,The idea you give me to do this helped me thanks man @Sagar Acharya

Answer (score 1):

Using animation gives you more controll

```
class MyCircularIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCircularIndicatorState createState() => _MyCircularIndicatorState();
}

class _MyCircularIndicatorState extends State<MyCircularIndicator> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  double myAnimationValue = 0;// 0 to 100
  Color beginColor,endColor;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //initiate animation controller
    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text((myAnimationValue).toInt().toString()),
        CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: Tween<Color>(begin:beginColor,end:endColor).animate(controller),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

somewhere in your widget, call set state when the value changes, adjust coloring according to your requirement

```
setState(() {
 myAnimationValue = //set your value within 1-100;
 controller.value = myAnimationValue/100;
})
```